# viewing cctv footage

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, video, vlc

is out there soft to watch cctv footage from pc on LAN without internet access. it consists of 3 ip cams (hikvision), router & laptop w ubuntu on it.

i can play live feed using vlc player but i cant get to recorded video. cams have microsd in themselves and footage is stored there. also it uses ethernet cables no wifi.

i dont want to have to download it before i can watch it.

online everywhere is watching it via internet explorer but its internet explorer so. another thing, every single soft ive found is about recording it and watching that recorded stuff. i dont wanna record it on disk, it has microsd, i wanna use that

Comment: Have you tried other browser to access the camera's web server? That's where and how you can manage those cameras. The answer below gives a good idea but if it wasn't previously set then you must access the camera settings directly for that typically a web browser is used. It typically doesn't have to be the deprecated IE but indeed some cheap old cams do require some ActiveX only available in IE. That being the case update their firmware and if there isn't any then replace them with something modern and decent.

Answer (score 2):

Check if maybe those cameras export a Samba (CIFS) mount. If they do, it should be easy to simply mount them on your Ubuntu machine and play the videos from there with vlc or whatever video player you like best (IMHO vlc **is** the best).